# number() sometimes contains a comma and a decimal. How can I check if it's a number

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm testing whether or not the first node of a document has a number value.
I tried doing this by simply doing

```
<xsl:when test="number(//ss:wd[0])">    <!---ss: being the namespace prefix-->
<!--- My code -->
</xsl:when>
```

However, it is not returning the expected the results. I believe that this is because the value being checked sometimes has commas and/or a decimal.

So, does XSLT not think that '1.1' or 1,000.1' are numbers?
And how can I get around this issue?

Added:
I'm using choose and when because I want to check other options, such as if it has a specific value

Comment: [`number()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-number) doesn't do grouping separators, but it should definitely [do a decimal point](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Number).

Comment: There's one aspect confirmed, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT/XPath is not able to deal with grouping selectors. Use `translate` before using `number()` to test it to remove them (although this can lead to some non-numbers to slip through, like `,,,0` and similar).

```
number(translate(//ss:wd[0], ',', ''))
```

Comment: What happens if the number does not have a comma? Does the code return an error?

Comment: No, it doesn't. The `translate` call just removes all comma characters.

Answer (score 4):

> So, does XSLT not think that '1.1' or 1,000.1' are numbers?

The number() function (which BTW is an XPath function, not XSLT) considers "1.1" to be a number, and "1,000.1" to be NaN (Not A Number). IOW, a decimal period is recognized, a comma - in any role - is not.

You may translate the comma out before performing the test - assuming that is the only obstacle here.